# Always Display an App?

Tags: xcode, ios6

I was wondering if it was possible to make it so an ipod always displays an app, even after you restart the device? I am doing a project for a museum, and they dont want the visitors to hold down the power button and be able to exit the app, is there any way to have it so it boots straight to the app? Thank you

Comment: Any particular reason they don't just slap a case on the iPad that blocks access to the power button?

Comment: I don't think what you are trying to achieve is possible, however, Kevin's suggestion seems the best alternative. Just remove physical access to the home button.

Comment: We have a case on that protects the home button, but we need to use the standby button to put the ipods to sleep so we dont waste battery

Comment: Yes that is possible - google for iOS Kiosk Mode - things like the following walkthrough will come up: http://www.42gears.com/blog/2012/08/how-to-convert-ipad-into-kiosk-device/

Comment: But is there any way to do this in Xcode? this looks good so far, and im installing the profile now, but i dont want to have to pay for it, or have it become paid for in the future.

Comment: No, you can not lock your device using an app (if your device is not jailbroken).

Comment: Okay, I will give Till's post a try, thank you.

Comment: Even better and ez to do: http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/25/enable-guided-access-ios/

Comment: The first one I tried didnt work, after restarting the device, it still is at the home screen.